# SpriteKit Scene order

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scene

I'm creating a game using Sprite Kit. I have my `GameScene` and `GameOverScene`now I want to create a `MenuScene` Where do I control the order of the MenuScene so that it shows up after `LaunchScene`

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("MenuScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Edit tried putting `("MenuScene")` as the scene but when I run the game that scene won't show

Comment: Check your main view controller, it calls the first scene that shows up.

Comment: Check my edit. It doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found out that I was one the right path. I just needed to change this line. Instead of this
`if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("MenuScene") as? GameScene {` 
add this
`if let scene = MenuScene.unarchiveFromFile("MenuScene") as? MenuScene {`